# Export CSV in Google Sheets with double quotes outputs 3 double quotes

Tags: google-sheets

I'm exporting data from a Google Sheets spreadsheet and need to import it in another application that requires one double quotation mark at the start and end of each cell. So the date in the Google Sheets spreadsheet looks like this:

```
"name","description","colour","shape","currency","cost","delivery-date"
"apple","fruit","red","round","gbp","5","2021-09-14"
"orange","fruit","orange","round","gbp","6","2021-09-18"
```

But when I go to the Google Sheets menu and click File > Download > CSV it exports the data with 3 double quotation marks and it looks like this, and the other application doesn't like it:

```
"""name""","""description""","""colour""","""shape""","""currency""","""cost""","""delivery-date"""
"""apple""","""fruit""","""red""","""round""","""gbp""","""5""","""2021-09-14"""
"""orange""","""fruit""","""orange""","""round""","""gbp""","""6""","""2021-09-18"""
```

How can I get Google Sheets to export the data with just one double quotation mark at the start and end of each cell?

Here's a link to view the spreadsheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1r3OFqES0Nugd2klA70AzAcjRKY0i_riJ3K46_h2fYxA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: can you share a copy of your spreadsheet ? and your devlopemnt.

Comment: As Mike requested, share a view only link to your sheet please

Comment: Here's a link to view the spreadsheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1r3OFqES0Nugd2klA70AzAcjRKY0i_riJ3K46_h2fYxA/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make a script (add Drive API Service) :

```
function createGoogleDriveTextFile() {
  var fileName = "yourSheet_" + new Date().toString().slice(0,15) + ".csv";
  var data = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('yourSheet').getDataRange().getDisplayValues(); 
  var content = data.map(l => '"' + l.join('","') + '"').join('\n')
  var newFile = DriveApp.createFile(fileName,content);
};
```

the file will be stored in the root of your drive. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Tpjk19SZsP_y9HFBhY5HtQMk4u2Mu-HKj1jUhq4jk4c/copy

Comment: I tried this but it still exports 3 quotation marks around the cell text.

Comment: Thanks, I'm unfamiliar with scripting but just clicked on your link, agreed to make a copy of your file, opened the script editor, run the script, downloaded the output file, added the extension ".CSV". I hope that's the right way to do this? When I open the file it has two double quotation marks before each cell text and two after each cell text. But I need a single quotation mark before and after each cell text.

Comment: so, replace by `content+='"'+data[i][j]+'",'` - take a new copy, I have updated my answer

Comment: this woulld break if there are \n (breaked lines) in any cells, wouldn't it?

Comment: in that situation add before .map() function `data.forEach(function(cel){cel = cel.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r|\t|  )/gm,"")})`